# How to set the values in array of json response

Tags: java

```html
below code is json response which i am getting from external service
{
 "dates": {
    "transced": "tran",
    "medical_bill_date": "2012-09-17",
    "medical_startdate": "2016-09-21",
    "union_date": "2016-05-20",
    "billed_dates": [
      {
        "start_date": "2016-06-27",
        "end_date": "2017-03-20"
      }
]
}
}
exception getting as invalid path

I am getting as invalid path.
Invalid path -> $.dates.billed_dates[0].start_date"
```

Comment: please read this [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Your json message is not a valid one. No start and end curly braces. try with below json message

```
{
   "dates": {
      "transced": "tran",
      "medical_bill_date": "2012-09-17",
      "medical_startdate": "2016-09-21",
      "union_date": "2016-05-20",
      "billed_dates": [
        {
            "start_date": "2016-06-27",
            "end_date": "2017-03-20"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the JSON in OP's question, just the closing braces are formatted slightly differently.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave before down my answer you had to checked the answered time and edited time.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't spot that, but still, as the post stands this answer doesn't add anything. Given that the intent of StackOverflow is to create a repository of knowledge that will help people in future, then the answers need to be relevant for the question in its current state. This isn't, so unfortunately it should be downvoted as, currently "This answer is not useful".

Comment: I'd add that there's little point trying to guess at what OPs problem is, given the lack of useful information that's been included in the question. Unless it's edited, the question is likely to be closed anyway, either as unclear or OT because there's no MCVE.